# Installer pane next button listener

Tags: objective-c, installation

I'm working on an installer plug in which currently looks like this:

[image]

Currently I disable the "Continue" button with `[self setNextEnabled:NO]` until all fields are input. What I would like to be able to do is actually run some code when the next button is clicked. Here I would ping the server, and only actually go to the next pane if I get pong.

How do I have a listener for this button?

My code goes a little like this:

```
#import "MyInstallerPane.h"

@implementation MyInstallerPane

- (void)didEnterPane:(InstallerSectionDirection)dir{
    [self toggleContinueButton];
    [self initTempDir];
}

.. + my own functions..
```

Comment: How to make the continue button gray?  `[self setNextEnabled:NO];` doesn't work for me

Comment: @jimwan Make sure your `xib` and `.h` files are connected (you should be able to drag from the `xib` to the `.h` to make an `IBOutlet`. Then, as above, make you `@implement`  the `.h` in the `.m` file

Comment: i found the reason is that this is the first page.I insert it before the introduction page  And i can disable the button in the other pages with the same code. Do you know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the delegate method

`- (BOOL)shouldExitPane:(InstallerSectionDirection)dir;`

> A subclass should override this method if it needs to prevent the
>   InstallerPane from exiting. Called to determine if a pane should exit
>   and allow another pane to be display on screen. Once the InstallerPane
>   decides it is time to exit, it can call gotoNextPane or
>   gotoPreviousPane  to exit without calling shouldExitPane again.

For example:

```
- (BOOL)shouldExitPane:(InstallerSectionDirection)dir {

    if (!good) {
      return NO
    }

    return YES

}
```